# Integrating without `polar_lift`

Tags: sympy

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
c, k = symbols('c, k', real=True, nonnegative=True)

integrate(exp(-c * k * x**2), (x, -oo, oo))
```

Produces

```
(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(polar_lift(c))*sqrt(polar_lift(k))/(c*k)
```

I don't want `polar_lift` in the output, is there an assumption I can add, or something else I can do to get a cleaner result?

Comment: According to the `polar_lift` docs you can set `polar=True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the symbols to be nonnegative which implies the possibility that they are both zero in which case the integral does not converge. If the symbols are both positive (i.e. not zero) then you get a simple result:

```
In [85]: x = Symbol('x')

In [86]: c, k = symbols('c, k', positive=True)

In [87]: integrate(exp(-c * k * x**2), (x, -oo, oo))
Out[87]: 
  √π 
─────
√c⋅√k
```